# Making the script to return fail in Mocha

Tags: node.js, selenium, mocha.js

I am trying to get the script to fail by accessing/redirecting to 2 links first before reaching to the error case. But i am still getting "1 passing" in mocha and then return error when it reaches the assertion. How do I make them wait for the script to completely finish only throw the error in mocha?

```
  describe("youtube", function(){
    it("test successful login",function(){
        var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        const pageLoad = By.id('lga')
        return driver.wait(until.elementLocated(pageLoad)).then(()=>{

            return setTimeout(function(){
                driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

                const signedPageLoad = By.id('pagelet_bluebar')

                return driver.wait(until.elementLocated(signedPageLoad)).then(()=>{
                      //assert.strictEqual(, message);


                        assert.equal(50, 70); /*AssertionError: 50 == 70 */

                })
            },1000)
        })
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell mocha when the test should end. You can pass `done` and mocha will wait for the test result until that function is called

```
describe("youtube", function(){
    it("test successful login",function(done){
        var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        const pageLoad = By.id('lga')
        return driver.wait(until.elementLocated(pageLoad)).then(()=>{

            return setTimeout(function(){
                driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

                const signedPageLoad = By.id('pagelet_bluebar')

                return driver.wait(until.elementLocated(signedPageLoad)).then(()=>{
                      //assert.strictEqual(, message);


                        assert.equal(50, 70); /*AssertionError: 50 == 70 */
                        done(); // call this function to tell mocha that you are done. 
                })
            },1000)
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: hi @AbhinavD, i happen to get this error in the console. "Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.". Do you happen to know whats that about?

Comment: I can take a look. Please post the relevant code, preferably in a separate question as others would find it easy to spot and answer

Comment: Thanks. Ive created it at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50712386/finishing-the-mocha-script-done-returns-resolution-method-is-overspecified