# finishing the mocha script done returns Resolution method is overspecified

Tags: node.js, selenium, mocha.js

Access to two links and then call it done when its finished returns me "Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both"

```
describe("youtube", function(){
    this.timeout(8000);
    it("test successful login",function(done){
        var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        const pageLoad = By.id('lga')
        return driver.wait(until.elementLocated(pageLoad)).then(()=>{

            return setTimeout(function(){
                driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

                const signedPageLoad = By.id('pagelet_bluebar')

                return driver.wait(until.elementLocated(signedPageLoad)).then(()=>{
                      //assert.strictEqual(, message);


                                                    done(); // call this function to tell mocha that you are done. 
                })
            },1000)
        })
    })
})
```

How is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning a `promise` and `done` are incompatible.

I think you should remove all `return` statements from the code

Comment: ur explanation is very understandable. with that understanding im able to tweak more by playing with assert n catch error

Answer (score 1):

@AbhinavD helped me to understand n am able to edit the code to  be more flexible by adding assertion and catch errors.

```
it("test successful login",function(done){
    var driver = new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

    const pageLoad = By.id('lga')
    driver.wait(until.elementLocated(pageLoad)).then(()=>{

        setTimeout(function(){
            driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");

            const signedPageLoad = By.id('pagelet_bluebar')

            driver.wait(until.elementLocated(signedPageLoad)).then(()=>{
                  //assert.strictEqual(, message);
                    assert.equal(50, 70); 
                    done(); // call this function to tell mocha that you are done. 
            }).catch((err) => done(err));
        },1000)
    }).catch((err) => done(err));
})
```